# Unable to access the SP2013 App from IE but able to access from chrome

Tags: list, javascript, app, sharepoint-addin

I've started working on SP2013 App development. When I'm deploying the app from VS2012, the App is successfully getting deployed. But after Trusting the app, it is showing "Internet cannot display the webpage" on IE9. But it is working as expected in Chrome. This is same in the case of publishing the app and uploading it as well. I've made all required internet setting for IE.

Thanks in advance,
Akanksha

Comment: After trusting the app, you will be taken to the start page for the app. Is the app web on a separate domain? Have you made the appropriate DNS changes to support resolution of URLs in the app domain? Can you confirm the URLs match in IE9 (where you're seeing the 404 error) and Chrome (where you can see the start page)?

Comment: App domain has been configured properly in DNS. I've copied and pasted the url from IE9 to chrome and it is working fine. The start page of app is not opening in IE9.